# New Install 14.04, Dell 2720 AIO, kernal error

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia

New install on a Windows based Dell 2720 with 32GB SSD reconfigured as non-cache disk. UEFI system, to dual boot with Windows 10.
Root set to 32GB SSD; swap to 32GB partition on 2TB hard dve, /home to hd dve.
Install went happily. Yea! Boot Ubuntu!
First attempt, pink screen hang. No Ubuntu logo or load dots.
Second attempt, kernel crash into (unknown to me) system shell. Large font text overscrolled. Looks like register contents, stack addresses and call trace ("nouveau" features on many lines)...blinking cursor.
Replace USB install drive.. Boots to same kernal crash, but with smaller
 font:

19.431161] divide error: 0000 [#1] SMP

19.431186] Modules linked in: hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid usb_storage rtsx_pcisdmmc nouveau(+) i915 mxm_wmi ttmn i2c_algo_bit psmouse ahci drm_kms_helper libahci r8169 drm mii floppy video wmi

19.431266] CPU: 1 PID: 152 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu

19.431284] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 2720/05R2TK  , BIOS A11 07/21/2015

19.431300] task: ffff8802722147d0 ti: ffff88003646a000 task.ti: ffff88003646a000

then a bunch of register or address contents in similar hex values, followed by stack details and a call trace which features numerous "nouveau" references.
I gather from another forum question that it has something to do with the kernal having issues using the generic Nouveau graphics driver instead on the Nvidia driver. Ubuntu showed a dialog box with options to select NVidia, but wouldn't accept them, and enforces the generic Nouveau option, resulting in the same problem. I can't remember if it was during a reinstall attempt or running in USB "try Ubuntu" mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try 15.04 or 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Default Noveau x-windows driver problem caused either pink splash screen or hex trace diagnostics. Found http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132. This thread explained how to boot with "nomodeset". Upon booting, opened system settings->software updates->drivers and installed a proprietary Nvidia driver and rebooted. Linux liftoff. –  I posted this as a comment earlier, but it should have been an answer.